# Расположить три блока на flex

Tags: css, flexbox

как на флексах сделать такое расположение блоков?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй блок занимает всю высоту и третий блок располагается под первым, не могу понять как 2 и 3-ий блок сделать друг под другом. Подскажите пожалуйста.
Оборачивать 2 и 3 блоки в обертку не выход, потому что в мобильной версии блок 1 будет стоять между 2 и 3 блоком.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
}

.first {
  width: 49%;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  order: 1;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
}

.second {
  width: 49%;
  height: 90px;
  order: 2;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
}

.third {
  width: 49%;
  height: 90px;
  order: 3;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="second">
    <div>Второй блок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="first">
    <div>Первый блок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    <div>Третий блок</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В разметке блоки стоит располагать по смысловому порядку, а визуальный порядок перетасовывать при помощи свойства `order` — так будет правильнее с т. з. семантики (хотя почему у вас ни в десктопной, ни в мобильной версии не планируется ставить первый блок на первое место — загадка).

Верстка такого блока фактически представляет собой флексбокс с вертикальной осью и переносом элементом на следующий ряд.

```css
:root {
  --grid-height: 200px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: var(--grid-height);
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.first {
  width: 49%;
  height: calc((var(--grid-height) / 2) - 5px);
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
}

.second {
  width: 49%;
  height: var(--grid-height);
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
  order: -1;
}

.third {
  width: 49%;
  height: calc((var(--grid-height) / 2) - 5px);
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    <div>Первый блок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <div>Второй блок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    <div>Третий блок</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пример с гридами. Использована функция `minmax()`, чтобы обойтись без медиавыражений, а высокий блок растягивается при помощи свойства `grid-row-end: span 2`

```css
:root {
  --grid-height: 200px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
}

.first {
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
}

.second {
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
  order: -1;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.third {
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    <div>Первый блок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <div>Второй блок</div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    <div>Третий блок</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Верстка идет как вы сказали по порядку, просто писал код для примера и перепутал блоки местами.
А если высота блоков не фиксированная? Как в этом случае быть? Просто высоту блоков указал для примера, чтобы видно было, а на проекте надо, чтобы справа блок имел возможность тянуться на высоту контента внутри блока.

Comment: Если надо, чтобы в мобильной версии было 1-2-3 по порядку, то без гридов или скриптов никак.

Comment: Хм, с гридами я еще не знакомился, а пример на гридах сильно сложный?)

Comment: Счас добавлю пример.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Если ваша разметка статическая и будет неизменна, вам ничто не мешает сгруппировать два элемента контейнером, в таком случае вы сможете оперировать вашим wrapper, будто у вас 2 дочерних элемента. И поведение flex по-умолчанию вам как-раз подойдет. И соответственно, сгруппированные элементы можете уже позиционировать внутри контейнера как угодно. Но это если верстка статическая и никогда не изменится :)

Comment: @Lilliance если вы имеете в виду группировку первого и третьего блока, то потом эти блоки нельзя будет перестроить в порядок 1-2-3 на маленьком разрешении.