# Расположение flex элементов

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть 3 элемента, в контейнере div (display flex). И мне нужно расположить их так, как нарисовано на картинке. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать на flex. Структуру элементов менять нельзя, иначе, я бы сам сделал. Спасибо.

```css
.block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #F0F6F8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.block_one {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 450px;
}

.block_two {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

                        <img src="https://img.lovepik.com/element/40118/6371.png_300.png">
                        
                        <div class="block_one">
                            <p>Simple text1</p>
                            <p>Simple text1</p>
                            <p>Simple text1</p>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="block_two">
                            <p>Simple text2</p>
                            <p>Simple text2</p>
                            <p>Simple text2</p>
                        </div>
                        
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите здесь:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/844745/346136

Comment: Хороший пример, но у меня не удается расположить так с моими блоками. Уже даже свои правила css удалил и применил все те, что в примере. Все равно, никак.

Comment: А чем Вас не устраивает обернуть два правых блока в один?

Comment: Если я нарушу дефолтность данной структуры, да и вообще, любой части DOM этого проекта, то это может повлечь некоторые неприятные последствия. Я бы сам обернул их в div и задал flex-direction:column, но нужно сделать с тем, что есть.

Comment: @sergey kuznetsov Мне непонятно что ты хочешь сделать. Сделай хоть картинку на основе своего кода как это должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать таким решением Расположение.

```css
.block {
  display: table;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.block img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.block_one {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 450px;
  float: right;
  border: 8px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}

.block_two {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  border: 8px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://img.lovepik.com/element/40118/6371.png_300.png">
  <div class="block_one">
    <p>Simple text1</p>
    <p>Simple text1</p>
    <p>Simple text1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block_two">
    <p>Simple text2</p>
    <p>Simple text2</p>
    <p>Simple text2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```